# How do I authenticate with Google's REST services using a GoogleSignInAccount?

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

I'm writing an Android application that needs access to Google's Calendar API. I'd like to avoid using the Google API Client Library in favor of a simple Retrofit REST implementation. However, I can't seem to get the right authorization credentials in order to complete Calendar API REST calls. In my app, I sign in successfully with the following options:

```
    GoogleSignInOptions
        .Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestScopes(Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"))
        .requestEmail()
        .requestIdToken("WEB CLIENT ID HERE")
        .build()
```

And I end up with a `GoogleSignInAccount` that gives me access to an `idToken` property. I've tried using this `idToken` as an OAuth 2.0 Bearer token in the authorization header of my request to the Calendar API, but I get rejected with a `401` every time. There's a lot of documentation around Google's OAuth process that seems to contradict itself or has escaped being updated, but it makes things very confusing. Any ideas about what I need to do in order to be able to use the REST APIs from my Android application?

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem?

Comment: I ended up using the native SDK as it was much less of a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, for the answer, I in-between managed to find out how to use the GoogleSignInAccount to authenticate the API-requests.

After you successfully signed in to your account using the [google_sign_in](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_sign_in) plugin
(see the [example](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_sign_in/example/lib/main.dart) for help) you can get the authentication headers that are required for the authentication of your api-request directly from the GoogleSignInAccount. 
See:

```
GoogleSignInAccount _currentUser;
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> _getLabels() await {
  http.Response _response = await http.get(
    'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/'+_currentUser.id+'/labels',
    headers: await currentUser.authHeaders,
  );
  return jsonDecode(_response);
}
```

Comment: That's Dart, not Java. Also play-services-base:16.x's GoogleSignInAccount has no getter nor field for authHeaders; I wonder if it's an extension method?

Nope, it's provided by the API: https://pub.dev/documentation/google_sign_in/latest/google_sign_in/GoogleSignInAccount-class.html

Answer (score 0):

authHeaders is implemented in Dart only, the source can be checked at https://pub.dev/documentation/google_sign_in/latest/google_sign_in/GoogleSignInAccount-class.html .

So the authHeaders are as follows:

```
"Authorization": "Bearer $accessToken",
    "X-Goog-AuthUser": "0",
```

Now how can I obtain accessToken? Dart is calling `GoogleSignInPlatform.instance.getTokens(email, shouldRecoverAuth: true)`; the impl of that method can be found here: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_sign_in/google_sign_in_platform_interface/lib/src/method_channel_google_sign_in.dart#L50

Aaaaand I'm giving up on this Google crap:

1. There is this magical chapter  [Obtain an access token from the Google Authorization Server.](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#2.-obtain-an-access-token-from-the-google-authorization-server.) which says absolutely nothing on how to obtain access token. A prime example of shitty chatty useless doc that Google produces en masse.
2. The docu further sends me to https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/ which still doesn't explain how to get the accessToken.
3. That doc portal sends me to https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start?authuser=2 which again talks web client instead of Android client, and I'm powerless. My limbs stop to move, my brain melts, my mouth opened in an endless silent scream of horror. This is how hell must look like. Reading Google docs is how hell must look like.